# What is the difference between an environment and a virtual environment?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

I have created a conda environment from a envornment.yml file and will be working in a jupyter notebook.

Is this environment a virtual environment? What is the difference between this and an "active" one? If it is virtual, I believe I have to install ipykernel. Can someone tell me what this does? Do I always need to install ipykernel or is it only with jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conda environment in itself is a virtual environment
the Jupyter notebook is not an environment, it's your code and you probably have to pick which environment you're working with while running said code

I don't think I ever installed ipykernel, and from what I read it's related to your Jupyter notebook, it's not environment related
so you need it when using a Jupyer notbook , but not if you're running a python script

I'm not sure what you mean by the active question,
but the way environments work is it separates the installations of different libraries
for example :

first_env: python 3.5 numpy 1.1

second_env: python 2 numpy 1.0

and for you to pick which python version and numpy version you want you need to activate the environment you need
so if you need py 3.5 you do

```
conda activate first_env
```

and then run your code in the same terminal
or you could pick your environment through the IDE

to check what environments you currently have do

```
conda env list
```

to check what libraries each env has you need to activate the env and then do

```
conda list
```

or

```
pip list
```

Here's the Conda [documentation](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html) in case you need it